# Making a Safari Reader-style application

Tags: java, html, interpreter

I've been inspired by Safari's Reader feature, which lets you ignore all content on a webpage except the story (all the text, links, and images which comprise the point of the page, but none of the markup, antecedents, or consequents). I want to make a **Java-based** version of it as a lightweight "browser".

My problem is herein: I don't know exactly how to discern the main content. Upon inspection of such Reader-recognized pages as [MSN articles](http://nbcpolitics.msnbc.msn.com/_news/2012/06/25/12398271-high-court-strikes-down-key-parts-of-arizona-immigration-law?lite/) and [fan fictions](http://www.fimfiction.net/story/11863/1/Just-Relax/Just-Relax), I realized that the actual text that Reader recognizes is not only hard to find, but inconsistent and broken up with seemingly random tags. For instance, whereas the news link starts its story with `<div class="postBody">` and every paragraph is in `<p>`s, the fiction linked starts with `<div class="chapter_content" id="chapter_container">` and every paragraph starts with `<br /><div style='float:left; height:1.0em; width:3.0em;'></div>` but is not within its own container.

Since Safari supprots this "Reader" interface, there obviously IS a way of doing this, so I won't ask if it exists. Instead, I want to know this: **What is a good, fast, *Java-supported* algorithm for extracting the title and body of a story on a webpage, regardless of how the page, itself, is constructed?**

For context, I've already created a basic browser with a JEditorPane as the window, whose EditorKit is set to be an HTMLEditorKit, and am using the `setPage(URL page)` method to show the target page, but this can change i needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use a service, you should look into the [Instapaper](http://www.instapaper.com/api/simple) or [Readability](http://www.readability.com/developers/api) APIs; otherwise, you can peep into [arc90 lab's JavaScript proof-of-concept implementation](http://code.google.com/p/arc90labs-readability/) of Readability. You can also find [several](https://github.com/karussell/snacktory) [ports](https://github.com/ymiyata/java-articleparser) [of Readability](https://github.com/basis-technology-corp/Java-readability) to Java and [several](https://github.com/arrix/node-readability) [other](https://github.com/kingwkb/readability) [languages](https://github.com/feelinglucky/php-readability) on GitHub.